# about creating PFK relationships from table that have PK from 2 column

Tags: sql, relationship

how to create a fk column to pk column made from 2 columns
i can do this ?
its  ( isa ) relationships
but the pk is from 2 columns
and in the ERD and DSD its more easy to understand what i want to ask

[image: ERD]

[image: DSD]

i am trying to create that pfk in PC table from column that pk in Product table but i have 2 Columns of pk in Product table 
i am trying to create it in SQL

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you create a foreign to two columns using:

```
alter table t add constraint fk_t_col1_col1
    foreign key (col1, col2) references othertable(col1, col2);
```

I'm not 100% sure this answers your question, but it is tagged SQL.

As a note:  I generally recommend having single column auto-incremented primary keys.  This definitely simplifies foreign key relationships.

Comment: I need to create 1 fk col to 1 pk col but the pk is from 2 col

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
create table Product
(
maker nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
model int NOT NULL,
type1 nvarchar(50),

constraint PK_Product Primary Key (maker,model)
)
```

it worked for me,  but i didn't know how to create the PFK, I'll be thankful if you can help :)

Comment: In the other table u need to make a primary key that reference from the pk in the first table “father table”  so u make a pk that is fk from another table but the problem was that 2 column of pk i have in the father table so my solution to make the pk column that i need to use it in the son table unique so i can do that without any problem i hope u understand me if not i will write code for u